# Setup.py: How to add external installation candidates?

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

I want to configure my `setup.py` file for a proper installation. Packages and programs which
are available through PYPI are no problem thanks to the parameter `install_requires`. Additionally I need to deploy external packages like `xvfb`.

Can you recommend me a way how to add external dependencies / packages / programs to my 
`setup.py` installation?

**My current setup.py file**

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name = 'package_name',
    version = '0.3.1',
    packages = find_packages('src'),
    package_dir={'':'src'},
    install_requires=['selenium', 'nose',])
```

**EDIT:** The goal is to create an installation skript which installs the required packages and the external candidates like this:

```
>>> sudo python setup.py install 
# installs selenium, nose and for instance xvfb through e.g. apt-get.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, `setup.py` does not allow any other dependencies, except python's (PYPI). You can try build `deb` packages for your module.

Check this tutorial:
https://wiki.debian.org/Python/Packaging

Answer (score -4):

What's about standard python import when you run program?

```
try :
     import mypackage
catch ImportException:
     print ("Cannot load package mypackage")
```